# Creating a method in C# that can take double, decimal, and floats without repeating code

Tags: c#, generics, dry

I'm trying to not repeat code unnecessarily. I have this method which I want to return true or false based on a basic calculation. The arguments for the value could be `double`, `float`, `decimal`.

This was my (failed) attempt. Any guidance would be appreciated.

```
private bool DoMyThingGeneric(Type type, object value)
{
    // I'm trying to do something like this:
    // cast "value" to "type"
    var constructed = type.MakeGenericType();

    object obj = Activator.CreateInstance(constructed);

    // assign "value" to "d" - THIS DOESN'T WORK
    var endVal = obj as typeof(type);


    if (Math.Floor(endVal * 1000) == endVal * 1000)
    {
        return true;
    }

    return false;
}

private bool DoMyThing(decimal x)
{
    DoMyThingGeneric(x.GetType(), x);

    return false;
}

private bool DoMyThing(float x)
{
    DoMyThingGeneric(x.GetType(), x);

    return false;
}

private bool DoMyThing(double x)
{
    DoMyThingGeneric(x.GetType(), x);

    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Repeat the code. Or cast.

As generics can not have operators.... there is no alternarive.

Comment: The alternative is `dynamic`, although that would have a major performance impact.

Answer (score 4):

In C#, you have the following options.

1. Repeat the code.
2. Implement the operation using the widest required type, and then cast the result (e.g. if you need to support just `double` and `float`, you could implement support for `float` by calling the `double` method and casting the result to `float`). This is not always an option since the range and precision of the various types doesn't always overlap.
3. Create a private implementation method that uses `dynamic` arguments. This would avoid some code duplication at the expense of type safety and have a substantial performance impact.
4. Create an interface defining your methods, and use reflection to generate the appropriate code to implement the various interface methods dynamically. This would be less maintainable than the first option, challenging to implement correctly, and almost certainly longer than just duplicating the code.

Most application code involving a choice between `float`, `double`, and `decimal` is either so simple that it is easily duplicated, or so performance sensitive that duplication is required to meet the target goals. Repeating the code is almost always the best available option.

Comment: It's too bad .NET didn't define a numeric type which could precisely represent any value from any numeric primitive type.  Sixteen bytes (the size of `Decimal`) would have been sufficient to do so, but the dynamic range of `Decimal` is artificially constrained to be much smaller than `Double`.

Answer (score 1):

Using the dynamic keyword will work for you...

```
private bool DoMyThing<T>(T x)
{
    if (Math.Floor((dynamic) x*1000) == (dynamic) x*1000)
        return true;
    return false;
}
```

Bear in mind that you lose compile time type safety and some performance... it just depends on if the trade-offs are worth it for your case.

Comment: The overloads are unneeded, plus you fail to mention the cost of using dynamic

Comment: Your right... the overloads are unnecessary... I had initially intended to limit the types allowed but scrubbed that from what I posted.

Comment: Since .NET 2.0, `Math.Floor` has had overloads for `double` and `decimal`. If `x` is of neither type, the call will throw a `RuntimeBinderException` complaining that the call is ambiguous between the two overloads.